Quartz crystals: Is it "load capacitance" or "loading capacitance"?
Quartz crystals have a certain load capacitance that needs to be matched with parasitic capacitance and additional external capacitors.
However, I'm not sure how to read this term. Is it "load capacitance" as in:

applying a "load" to the crystal, or as in
"loading" something onto the crystal

This is of special interest to me, since I'm from Germany, where we would actually have two separate wordings for both cases ("Lastkapazität" and "Ladekapazität"). To make matters worse, I've seen both cases being used, so others must suffer from my misconception too. And while I see a clear preference of the first case over the latter, I'd like to have confirmation on that topic.
What is the right interpretation, and, if there is time, why?

Hmm I would say both of the descriptions are the same. At least stated like that in English. I would say the first term as you say is the most commonly used. The other one I have never really heard or considered. But then again English is also not my native tongue, so just my opinion.

Strictly speaking, the capacitors applied either side of a crystal in a Pierce oscillator neither load the crystal nor are loading the crystal. Those capacitors ensure that there is an impedance change equal to 180° at a specific and desired frequency. For instance, if you used one capacitor and plotted the spectrum of input to output it would look like this (taken from my basic website): -

For various values of CL we see these bode-plot responses: -

The phase shift never quite reaches an unambiguous 180° so, using one so-called "loading capacitor" doesn't cut-the-mustard and, you need another capacitor before the crystal like this: -

CL1 and CL2 are jointly varied from 5 pF to 30 pF in increments of 5 pF: -

Clearly you get an unambiguous point where the phase change is 180° and this means an accurate and precise oscillation frequency in (for example) a pierce type oscillator.
But, do either of these capacitors (CL) load the crystal or, are they in fact just components that are used in creating a Pi-filter? The latter of course. So, does it really matter whether you call them load or loading capacitors <-- a big fat no because both terms are, strictly speaking, incorrect.

Opinion incoming.
Anything that is loading something else is a load. The difference, from a language perspective seems to be that "load" is a noun, and "loading" is an adjective or verb in this context, as in "a loading element", otherwise called "a load". The two forms are interchangeable.
However, I mostly use the term "load" to refer to some element using the signal or power from the previous stage that produced it. This is distinct in my mind from something that is there  deliberately or unintentionally, but whose role is merely ancillary.
For example, in the context of the crystal oscillator, I would say that the capacitors are "loading" the system with the intention of fine-tuning frequency, phase shifts or impedance matching, but I reserve the term "load" for whatever comes next, the thing connected to the oscillator output, actually receiving power, and actually making use of the signal.
That's purely a matter of preference, though, and I think you could correctly use either term, "loading capacitor", implying "a capacitor that is loading", or "load capacitor", implying "a capacitor acting as a load".
Another example that comes to mind is the feedback voltage divider used with linear regulators, R1 and R2 here:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Those resistors perform two functions, to provide feedback that determines output potential, and also to pass enough current to satisfy the LM317's "minimum load current" requirement, in the event that there's no "real" load present. I would not use the term "load resistors" to describe them, since they are clearly not the intended "load", but I would be happy to describe them as "loading" the regulator output. Subtle, and completely subjective, but that's my take on it.

Can we not use "load" as a verb?...as in, "Load the boat"? I think the context of loading capacitors here is specific to oscillators. Perhaps we should call them "feedback capacitors". Crystals can be used in filters too: in that context, associated capacitors are often called "coupling capacitors". Coupling is misleading since they greatly affect many filter characteristics like bandwidth, impedance. Your stated opinion is sensible to me.

@glen_geek Thanks! As an infinitive, "to load the boat", "load" is a verb, but "load the boat" uses "load" in the imperitive (I think that's the technical linguistic term), which doesn't fit the question of naming here. I'm no linguist though, and my English classes were 40 years ago.

Der Kondensator belastet den Quarz, er lädt ihn nicht auf. Setting aside the issue of whether a load capacitor really is a "load" electrically, you still have a genuine question.
"Load" in English has (at least) two closely-related meanings: the first is to place something onto a vehicle, or into a receptacle, for use or transport. You load a ship with cargo or passengers, load a weapon, load a file onto a computer. This usage aligns mostly with German laden, aufladen, or einladen. Sometimes we use "load up" for this meaning, which shows the kinship with aufladen. But we're not filling up the crystal, with charge or anything else.
The second meaning, per Oxford English Dictionary, is "to add or affix a weight to", "to be a weight or burden upon", "to increase the resistance in the working of (a machine) by the addition of a weight". The core meaning is almost the same, but the emphasis is on being weighed down by the load. That is, the load is a burden or ballast (another word sometimes used in electronics to signify a loading coil). If we use a preposition here we say that the thing is "loaded down" rather than "loaded up". This aligns with German "belasten". This is what we mean when we talk about a "load capacitance": it's capacitance provided to "drag down" the rate of change of voltage. Similarly for a load resistance or a load inductance.
All that said, according to my dictionary "beladen" is also a fine translation of the second meaning, so perhaps Ladekapazität isn't really wrong. But Lastkapazität seems like it's much less ambiguous in expressing what an EE has on their mind.

Looking at all answers up to now, there seems to be no definitive answer to this question, and in languages with different wordings, you're free to use both meanings interchangeably, and no one can really tell you otherwise. I guess the only way to ever decide that question would be to ask the original inventor...

First, I'm the OP and I think I know what I asked. Second, no one, including you, couldn't give more that an opinion, and even most opinions were completely undecided. Your comment is a complete and utter mistery to me. Maybe you care to elaborate a little more?
